# Robocopy Scripts

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

So I am looking for a nice batch file using the robocopy function to make a copy of my Win7 client machines Backup and Restore folders to a NAS. Each day a new folder is created in a backup set parent folder, so in theory, all I want robocopy to do is copy that new folder every night rather then the entire directory every night.

As of now - I am using robocopy /MIR but it still copies everything across each time as OLDER even though the folders haven't changed.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `/XO` option.

```
/XO : eXclude Older - if the destination file exists and is the same date
                      or newer than the source - don’t bother to overwrite it.
```

Another option would be to use the `/MaxAge:1` option.

```
/MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
```

[`RoboCopy /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Start backup time: %DATE% %TIME% >> g:\BC\backup_time.txt
robocopy.exe S:\ g:\BC\MK\ /MIR /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE /LOG:g:\BC\00_sync.log
echo End backup time: %DATE% %TIME% >> g:\BC\backup_time.txt
NET USE \\server01\IPC$ /USER:login password
NET USE \\fileserver\IPC$ /USER:login password
c:\reskit\robocopy \\fileserver\c$\work \\server01\e$\backup /MIR /SECFIX /TIMFIX /NP /LOG+:D:\logs\robocopy\backup_work.log
NET USE \\server01\IPC$ /DEL
NET USE \\fileserver\IPC$ /DEL
```